# system.web.security.membership Issue after rename data

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership

I have a issue. I renamed Database_A to Database_B. After that I can't use this

```
user = Membership.GetUser(strUserName)
```

to get user information because this refer to old database.
I see triggers also refer to old DB.

How can I correct this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the connectionString in your web.config that points to your membership database so it refers to "Database_B".

Comment: Sure, but This is not its cause. I'd changed connectionString before